# Why output of list is different within function than in main?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

My question is about LeetCode exercise [#24 : Swap nodes in pairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/):

> Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its head.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,3,4]
> Output: [2,1,4,3]
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: head = []
> Output: []
> ```
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1]
> Output: [1]
> ```

I included a `lprint()` function for printing a linked-list

When I create this list:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6
```

...call `swap`, and then call `lprint(head)` in the `__main__` area, then the first value of the linked list turns out to be still `1`:

```
1->4->3->6->5
```

While it should be:

```
2->1->4->3->6->5
```

But if I call `lprinf(head)` in the `def swap()` area, the answer is correct.

I don’t understand why there is this difference?

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
  next = None

def lprint(head):
  p = head
  while p:
    if p.next:
      print(p.val, end='->')
    else:
      print(p.val)
    p = p.next

def swap(head):
  if not head: return None
  p0, p1, p2 = None, head, head.next
  while p1 and p2:
    if not p0:
      p1.next, p2.next = p2.next, p1
      head = p2
      p1, p2 = p2, p1
      p0, p1, p2 = head, p1.next, p2.next
      if p1 and p2:
        p0, p1, p2 = p0.next, p1.next, p2.next
      else:
        break
    else:
      p0.next, p1.next, p2.next = p2, p2.next, p1
      p1, p2 = p2, p1
      p0, p1, p2 = p0.next, p1.next, p2.next
      if p1 and p2:
        p0, p1, p2 = p0.next, p1.next, p2.next
      else:
        break
  print('inner:',end=' ')
  lprint(head) # correct answer

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(6):
    if i == 0:
        head = p = Node(i+1)
    else:
        p.next = Node(i+1)
        p = p.next
  lprint(head) # before swap
  swap(head) 
  lprint(head) # wrong answer
```

Comment: Quick link to the exercise itself, may as well have this in your question: https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/

Comment: I don't think with leetcode exercise you should be using the `if __name_` block at all. Does the code execute or what does it give you as the error? Also, could you include the full code from leetcode so I can play around with it, I was having trouble with  the indentation when pasting your code there

Answer (score 0):

As to why it does not print the end result as expected: this is because the `swap` function modifies its local variable called `head`, but the caller is not informed about this change, and still has its own `head` variable referencing the node that originally was in first position, but is now in the second position. By consequence, printing that list will start from that second node, not the one that became first.

Note that the LeetCode challenge requires you to *return* a reference to the modified list. So your `swap` function should end with:

```
return head
```

...and your main code should take that returned value:

```
head = swap(head)
```

If you do that, the second call to `printl` will output what you expected.

Note however, that in a LeetCode challenge you are only expected to submit the `swap` function's implementation, as LeetCode will call that function itself, and verify the value that your function returns.